# How to take user input from a single line in NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and I am using python3 . I am learning numpy but cant figure out how to take user input from a single line. Like inputs--> 1 2 3 4

I have tried using this command which I generally used for normal array method other than numpy

```
from numpy import *
arr=array([])  
p=1

arr=list(map(int,append(arr,input().split())))


print(arr)
```

But the problem with this is that this is turning my array into a list and when I am using the command

```
print(arr.dtype)
```

It gives me this error--> **'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'**

So, my question is how to take input from a single line while using the numpy array module?

Comment: have u imported numpy module?
I have done --> from numpy import *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. split the input string into a list
2. convert the list to a numpy array

Code could be:

```
arr = np.array(input().split(), dtype='int')
```

---

This is the same for the array module, except that you must explicitely convert the values to an integral type:

```
arr = array.array('i', map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: another question, what to do while using the array module instead of the numpy module for the same problem, that is taking the input from the same line,

what I had done is this,
from array import *

arr=array('i',[])

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(arr)

but it is turning my array to list again

Answer (score 1):

use the built-in function "asarray" from numpy module

```
import numpy as np

# use asarray function of the numpy module. you can directly assign the data type too
usrInput = np.asarray(input().split(), dtype=np.int32)
print(type(usrInput))  # checking the type of the array
print(usrInput.dtype)  # check the data type
print(usrInput)  # display the output
```

you should see something like this in the output.

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
int32
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

I hope it's helpful.